# Supplied object, but invalid argument error in foreach loop appears

Tags: php, object, foreach, stdclass

I am getting the `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` when I run the following code:

```
foreach($combination as $combi){
         var_dump($combi);
         $tArr[]=$variant_options[$combi->product_variant_option_value_id];
                        }
```

When I var_dump `$combination`, I get `object(stdClass)#60 (8)//and the whole content`. So what's not okay with it?

I can also post the content of `$combination`, but it's a lot of it.

Any idea what I should do?

Thanks

Edit:
var_dump($combination) output:

```
    array(8) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#60 (8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["product_variant_option_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["product_variant_option_value_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["sku"]=> string(0) "" ["price"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["saleprice"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["quantity"]=> string(1) "0" ["weight"]=> string(1) "0" }


  [1]=> object(stdClass)#73 (8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["product_variant_option_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["product_variant_option_value_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["sku"]=> string(0) "" ["price"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["saleprice"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["quantity"]=> string(1) "0" ["weight"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

Edit2:

```
 foreach($variants as $variant){
         $combination=$this->Product_model->getVariationCombination($variant->id);
         $tArr=array();
         foreach($combination as $combi){
             $tArr[]=$variant_options[$combi->product_variant_option_value_id];
         }
```

where `getVariationCombination` is:

```
public function getVariationCombination($product_variant_id){
            $query=$this->db->get_where('product_variant_combination',array('product_variant_option_id'=>$product_variant_id));
            $variants=array();
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $variants[]=$row;
            }

            if(count($variants)>0) return $variants;
            return null;

        }
```

Comment: an object is not an array (ok, yes it could be but i assume not), no array - foreach complains.

Comment: @Rufinus `foreach` also iterates over objects.

Comment: @Bujanca Please post a *complete*, self contained example that allows us to reproduce the problem. It *should* work...

Comment: Alright, but `$combi` gets the correct content, the only problem is the notice.

Comment: @deceze does the update help in any way?

Comment: That looks even better, it's not even an object you're iterating over but an array. Which is to say, it's all the more unclear what the problem is.

Comment: please post the assignment of $combination this means the line where $combination is defined. like $combination = new Something(); etc.

Comment: @deceze `$combination` is an array, as its value is always provided by a function that either returns `null` or an array. As the output shows, `$combination` is not `null`

Comment: are you sure that the time the error occures $combination is not null? from the looks of it, it could very well be that the first time you iterate through foreach ($variants as $variant) it works but the second time $combination is null.

Comment: @gries yes, I have cleaned the code here, but I had put a `die()` after the first iteration in the second `foreach()` and the same error appears. Just after the assignment of `tArr`

Comment: can you post the output of:
foreach($variants as $variant){
         $combination=$this->Product_model->getVariationCombination($variant->id);
         $tArr=array();
          if (!is_array($combination)) {
              var_dump($combination);
              die('no array');
          }
         foreach($combination as $combi){
             $tArr[]=$variant_options[$combi->product_variant_option_value_id];
         }
but remove all your dies / var_dumps before that.

Comment: @gries Ok, I tried it and I get the same, it looks like it's always an array

Comment: hm could you post a version where you show us how your debug code looks like? there is still something missing as the described behaviour does not fit posted code.

Comment: I'm not really sure what I did there, but it works now. I change a lot of code, not sure what part solved it :(. Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 1):

to iterate over an object you have to implement an http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php or
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to complete gries' reponse.

1. for you to use foreach you need to have an array to loop in. For that you need to do what gries said.
2. the reason why your `var_dump` works is because an object is valid but you cannot loop through within the object's array of items like that. When you `print_r` an object or `var_dump` it may show you the properties as an array type looking output but it doesn't mean you can iterate it through it for a foreach